# Are White Walkers sentient beings with certain super-powers? If yes, what are their powers?

Tags: game-of-thrones, magical-creatures, powers

We don't know much about White Walkers besides they can attack and fight.

As far as I know, White Walkers were created by the Children of the Forest and the Three Eyed Raven (god who live in trees) with a piece of dragonglass through heart.

So, my questions is, are they sentient, intelligent beings capable of inventing weapons and thinking like humans, moreover blessed with superpowers?  If yes, what are those powers?

Comment: Please don't add the books tag. Your understanding of the whole affair is based on Show which is completely different on this subject when compared to the books. This will only confuse you or broaden the scope of your question. And fair warning, in books, not much is known about the Others.

Comment: Also please rephrase your question, otherwise people may VTC as too broad. If I understand correctly, you have only one question which is "Are White Walkers sentient beings with Super Powers?". I have edited your question on those lines. You can always roll back, and if you do, People can always VTC as too broad

Comment: I would say they are sentient, but not *sapient*. They have basic self-awareness, which is necessary for sentience. Not sure if they have the higher brain functions required for sapience. Then again, they have their own weapons and armor. They make plans. All are evidence in favor of sapience.

Answer (score 22):

Unsurprisingly, most of the White Walker (The Others) abilities revolve around ice and cold. I am going to draw on some back story from the *A Song of Ice and Fire* novels, but only where it is relevant to what we also see in the *Game of Thrones* show-verse.

- Create swords and other items from ice (seen in show):

  > Shaw: Do you know what substance an Other sword is made from.
  >
  > Martin: Ice. But not like regular old ice. The Others can do things with ice that we can't imagine and make substances of it.
  >
  > *["Interview with the Dragon" 2003 Robert Shaw](http://web.archive.org/web/20051103091500/nrctc.edu/fhq/vol1iss3/00103009.htm/)*
- Raise dead humans and animals as wights (seen in show, unclear if all White Walkers have this power or just the Night's King)
- Travel without leaving a trace in the snow (unclear if this is portrayed in the show)
- "Bring the cold with them" / white mist (seen in show)
- Speech, not exactly a "power", but as seen in the show it might just be thought of as screeching. This also lends credence to their sentience.

  > The Other said something in a language that Will did not know; his voice was like the cracking of ice on a winter lake, and the words were mocking. *- A Game of Thrones, Prologue*
- There is an obvious difference between the White Walkers and the wights they raise. The "leaders" are also shown to have some form of sentience. According to George R. R. Martin, the Others *"are strange, beautiful… think, oh… the Sidhe made of ice, something like that… a different sort of life… inhuman, elegant, dangerous."*

  > [Melisandre:] Necromancy animates these wights, yet they are still only dead flesh. Steel and fire will serve for them. The ones you call the Others are something more.
  >
  > [Stannis:] Demons made of snow and ice and cold. The ancient enemy. The only enemy that matters.
  >
  > *- A Storm of Swords, Chapter 78, Samwell V*

Comment: +1. The mandatory "Others are strange, beautiful… think, oh… the Sidhe made of ice, something like that… a different sort of life… inhuman, elegant, dangerous.", which answers the question if they can think or are sentient beings. They are a distinct intelligent species.

Comment: @Aegon You say don't include the book tag, yet the answer comes partially from the books?

Comment: @Edlothiad I can't comment on it's existing state, [when I commented](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/166664/1), it was derived from George's comments and the common powers without quotes (Such as raising the dead). Since the OP's perception is based on show and show is the one which has most info, I still don't think Books are needed.